# Buffer Dimensions Problems on Android 5.1

Tags: android

I'm using Infinix X510 on 5.1.1 Android version. When I compiled my android application to this device, I got this debug message every 500ms. How can I remove this debug message?

```
11-24 20:59:47.056 3051-3083 D/Surface: Surface::setBuffersDimensions(this=0xb45a7700,w=720,h=1280)
```